# Copy record from a table to another table + add own record

Tags: php, sql

I have a table name Users and a table name Application.

I want to insert 3 data into 3 columns (id,password,privilege) at Users table.

How do i extract 2 data from Application table (email_address,password) then i add own data in privilege column at Users table.

Sorry if this is confusing.

Comment: This is confusing. Please add your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following query:

```
INSERT INTO `Users` (id, password, privilege) 
SELECT email_address, password, 'privileges' FROM `Application`
```

Where `privileges` stands for the user privileges

Comment: you mean i can do like this :
INSERT INTO Users (id, password, privilege) 
SELECT email_address, password, 'my own data' FROM `Application`

Comment: @Genjo Yup, you can also use a variable instead, e.g. `$myData`